# need to build gemspec and install gem everytime in make a change in gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am creating a custom gem from scratch, and every time i make a change in the gem file, and restart the console, the change is not effective.

I need to build the gemspec and install the gem every time for my changes to be effective, is there any other approach to it that could save some of the time, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to test your gem functionality without build and install it every time. Just specify `path` option in your application `Gemfile` (not in your gem):

```
gem 'your gem name', path: 'path to your gem directory'
```

After that you can just restart application to reload changes in your gem.

[Here](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) is more details about `path` option.